# Power Query - Modify tables before combining them

Tags: powerquery

On my table (point1) I am trying to get, that for each table of the grouped rows (point 2) I will have new row inserted (point 3) at the beginning of each table with the value in the column "Metadata1" equal to value form "Column2" for original row number 2 (starting counting from 0).

Link to excel file:
https://filebin.net/cnb4pia0vvkg937g

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to know how much of your requirement is generic or specific, but

```
 TransformFirst = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepName",{{"Count", each 
 #table(
      {"Column1","Column2","Metadata1"},
      {{_{0}[Column1],_{0}[Column2],_{2}[Column2]}}
 ) & _
 }}),
Together=Table.Combine(TransformFirst[Count])
in Together
```

modifies all the tables in column **Count** to include an extra row that is made up up Row0/Col1  Row0/Col2 and Row2/Col2

It then combines all those tables into one table

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, your solution is giving me only first row from each group (form each table) whereas what I want is whole table rows + new inserted row as a copy of first one with the option to redefine some of values for defined column.

Comment: Then just use the second row  NewTable=Table.Combine(#"PriorStepName"[Count]) to combine them. I dont undertand what "copy of the first one means" but you can work from here

Comment: I see what you mean, however, my query is big and I am looking for a simple solution like "Table.InsertRows" but it is not working.

Comment: Since my code is a single line, not sure how much simpler it could get. Maybe if you described what this means by showing a sample: what I want is whole table rows + new inserted row as a copy of first one with the option to redefine some of values for defined column

Comment: Please look at my post, I edited the description and picture so that it is more clear now what I am trying to achieve, and there is also a test file.